# Which hook for Woocommerce single product thumbnail src link replacement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Is there any hook to change the single product thumbnail? I did search a lot on SO as well as over the internet but no luck.

With 'thumbnail' I don't mean changing the size of the current image but I want to completely change/replace the product image (thumbnail) with a new image based on some scenario.

```
public function pn_change_product_image_link( $html, $post_id ){

    $url =  get_post_meta( $post_id );
    $alt = get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) . ' ' .  __( 'thumbnail', 'txtdomain' );
    $attr = array( 'alt' => $alt );
    $attr = apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', $attr, NULL );
    $attr = array_map( 'esc_attr', $attr );
    $html = sprintf( '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/WP_Suspension_logo.svg/2000px-WP_Suspension_logo.svg.png"', esc_url($url) );
    foreach ( $attr as $name => $value ) {
        $html .= " $name=" . '"' . $value . '"';
    }
    $html .= ' />';
    return $html;
}
```

This is what I'm doing now but it's throwing an error.

Filter, Hook:

```
post_thumbnail_html
```

Comment: `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );` on template `single-product/product-image.php` … you can use `global $post, $product;` in your hooked function additionally

Comment: @Akash, see below link it will be helpful. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html

Comment: thumbnails are array of images, they are different from the main product image, check woocommerce template ```product-thumbnails.php``` and ```product-image.php``` and see where you can modify and add your filter

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm developing a plugin and the image of the product should be updated by my plugin so I cannot edit any template files.

Comment: @silver, I'm developing a plugin and the image of the product should be updated by my plugin so I cannot edit any template files.

Comment: did you check the template files I mentioned? you should be able to hook your modification on ```woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html```

Comment: @AkashAgrawal I know, I am not talking about editing templates, but I am showing you the correct filter hook `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html` that you can use with your function to hooked it in… and in your function you can add `global $post, $product;` to use either the `WP_Post` object or the `WC_Product` object…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the template `single-product/product-image.php` you can see all the source code that is displaying images on single product pages.

you could use `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html` as I have suggested in the comments, but it's not really useful, as you want to set a custom source link for the main image.

In the template source code you will see that it uses WordPress function `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` and in it's source code you will see that you can use the filter hook `'wp_get_attachment_image_src'` which is really convenient for what you want to do…

So now you can build your code on it:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', array( $this, 'pn_change_product_image_link'), 50, 4 );
public function pn_change_product_image_link( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ){
    if( ! is_product() ) return $image; // Only on single product pages
    if( $size == 'shop_thumbnail' ) return $image; // Not for gallery thumbnails (optional)

    // Your source image link
    $src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/WP_Suspension_logo.svg/2000px-WP_Suspension_logo.svg.png';
    $width  = ''; // <== (optional) define the width
    $height = ''; // <== (optional) define the height
    $image  = array( $src, $width, $height );

    return $image;
}
```

This code goes in any plugin file with a constructor *(but not in function.php file)*.

The code is tested and works.

> You can target dynamically different image sources using `$attachment_id` function argument…

---

**The theme  `function.php` file version**

Just replace:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', array( $this, 'pn_change_product_image_link'), 50, 4 );
```

By this

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'pn_change_product_image_link', 50, 4 );
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Comment: Amazing explanation!! This works like a charm. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
// define the woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html callback 
function filter_woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html( $sprintf, $post_id ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    // here you have product id too, fetch your data or re evalute things and return final image HTML
    return $sprintf; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'filter_woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This was more effective for me:

```
// add filter for that targets only single product main image
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'new_product_image' ), 10, 2 );

/**
 * Set the correct image rendition for product page hero images.
 *
 * @param string $html the html we won't be changing.
 * @param int    $post_thumbnail_id the part we want to change to our image id.
 *
 * @return string the html with altered source
 */
function new_product_image( $html, $post_thumbnail_id ) {
    // New Image source set here (target the field where you have the image)
    $img_id = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'new_products_img_id', true );

    if ( ! empty( $img_id ) ) {
        // We substitute in our image id 
        $html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $img_id, true );
    }
    return $html;
}
```